# django unit test class based view error No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing

I want to test my class based view.

Here is the models.py file:

```
class TodoList(models.Model):

    todoitem = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here is my views.py file

```
class ListTodoView(ListView):

    model = TodoList
    template_name = 'todolist_listview.html'
```

Here is my unit test:

```
class TestToDoListView(TestCase):

    def test_list_view(self):
        url = reverse('notes-list')
        resp = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(resp.status_code, 200)
        data = json.loads(resp.content) # getting error here No JSON object could be decoded
        self.assertEquals(len(data), 1)
```

What is the mistake that I am doing?
I have made sure, I have placed all the imports at place.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
======================================================================

ERROR: test_list_view 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../tests/test_views.py", line 21, in test_list_view
    data = json.loads(resp.content)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: add print resp.content before calling json.loads(resp.content) to check response content

Comment: it looks like you are rendering a template (html) from `ListView` what makes you think you are returning JSON?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do you test like this? What is the code in your html template? If there is a html code, it wrong to test like json data.

If you need return json data, it is wrong way to do.